# SharedElement transition in React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a problem when i tried to trasition between two screen. I expected something like example but i got very different thing. So i have create simple design to test it but i can't figured out how can i achive final result? I will upload video. So I only added two things in my HomePage and detail page where image is located.

Here is my ShareELement in my MainPage

```
   <SharedElement id="iamge">
      <Image
      source={images.bannerBg}
      resizeMode="cover"
      style={{
      width: "100%",
      height: "100%",
      borderRadius: 20,
      }
     />
  </SharedElement>
```

Here is my ShareELement in my DetailsPage

```
    <SharedElement id={"image"}>
     <Image
      source={images.bannerBg}
      resizeMode="cover"
      style={{
      width: "100%",
      height: "100%",
      }}
      />
  </SharedElement>
```

And also i added this in my DetailsPage

```
PlantDetail.sharedElements = (route, otherRoute, showing) => [
  { id: "image", animation: "fade-in" },
];
```

So my final result is

[image]

Expected something like

[image]

Sorry for my bad English!

Comment: on the `MainPage` its `<SharedElement id="iamge">`, whereas on the details page, `<SharedElement id={"image"}>` The ids are different

Comment: They  are same right now

Comment: Can you share your version of `react-navigation`